# Exception raised- NSTextView delegate- textViewDidChangeSelection: notification

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I am creating my first Mac app, a text editor. It is document-based, and the Document.xib has an nstextview. I have made the Document class the delegate of the textview. I am implementing the method:

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)notification
{
NSRange range=self.textView.selectedRange;
NSLog(@" %@ ",[[self.textView textStorage] attributesAtIndex: range.location
                                              effectiveRange: &range]);
```

I will be using the method call that is inside NSLog to get the attributes of selected text and update from that notification method the Underline button(pressed 
or not).
 The problem is that when the app runs and I press a key an exception is raised:
    an uncaught exception was raised

```
*** -[NSConcreteTextStorage attributesAtIndex:effectiveRange:]: Range or index   
out of bounds
```

I tried debugging by  a @try: @catch: block and it seems that the method as above always throws that exception. If I replace:

```
range.location
```

with

```
(range.location-1)
```

it throws that exception only when the cursor is at index 0.

Does anyone know what is happening?

Comment: range.location-1 is going to be an invalid number when self.textView.selectedRange==0 (no selection, or it starts at the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

**effectiveRange** is not the range used by the method to determine the range to scan for attributes. It is the range that will contain, upon return, the range over which the attributes and values are the same as those at the index attributeAtIndex (i.e. the method will assign a different value to your range variable).

If you want to limit the range used by the method to look for attributes to the selected range, use the following method with the rangeLimit set to the selected range:

**(NSDictionary *)attributesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index longestEffectiveRange:(NSRangePointer)aRange inRange:(NSRange)rangeLimit**

```
-(void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSRange selectedRange=self.textView.selectedRange;
    NSRange effectiveRange;
    if(selectedRange.length > 0) {
        NSLog(@" %@ ",[[self.textView textStorage] attributesAtIndex:selectedRange.location
       longestEffectiveRange:&effectiveRange inRange:selectedRange]); 
    }
}
```

It appears that the method does not work when the selectedRange length is 0. This is why the selectedRange.length is checked before calling it.

Comment: Thanks for your time. It crashes again(range or index out of bounds). Shouldn't effectiveRange be initialized? Is there anything Interface Builder-related that i may be missing?

Comment: Well, your textView property must be an IBOutlet connected to the actual NSTextView in IB. Have you checked the selectedRange values to see if they make sense (selectedRange.location, selectedRange.length)? effectiveRange will be initialized by the method (i.e. &effectiveRange).

Comment: Yes i have an NSLog at@finally (@try-@catch block)and they are perfectly fine. IBOutlet is set and so is the delegate of the textview.

Comment: Is there any chance that the fact that i don't have any prefix in my Document class (Document.m) messes anything with the runtime?

Comment: It seems that to get around this, you have skip the method when the selectedRange length is 0 (i.e. no selection) (see my edit above). Then you need an 'else' to determine what to do when there is no selection.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while for this thread but anyway I found this, should it be useful for anyone:

Calling - attributesAtIndex: still works fine when range.length == 0, but it fails when the location is at the end of the string. This is clearly a bug because the range {string_length, 0} IS A VALID range.

To overcome this, I use -typingAttributes: which gives the attributes for the current typing style.

```
NSRange currange = [self.textViewEditor selectedRange];
NSLog(@"range %@", NSStringFromRange(currange));
NSDictionary *dict;
if (currange.length==0)
    dict = [self.textViewEditor typingAttributes];
else
    dict = [self.textViewEditor.textStorage attributesAtIndex:currange.location effectiveRange:&range];
```